# How do I effectively preload conditional associations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following two models:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees # A company can have 1000's of employees.
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

One of my use cases looks like this

In the controller:

```
def my_action
  @companies = Company.where(country: 'GB').preload(:employees)
  @title = params[:title] # E.g. 'CTO'
end
```

In the view:

```
- @companies.each do |c|
  = c.employees.where(title: @title).first.last_name
```

The problem with the above is that it will create an N+1 in the view

Now I could change the view to:

```
# In the view
- @companies.each do |c|
  = c.employees.select{|e| e.title == @title}.first.last_name
```

This will solve the N+1 but it will still load out potentially 1000's of employee records even though I don't need them (I only need the ones with the right title).

I could solve that by:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
  has_many :ctos, ->{ where(title: 'CTO') }
end

# In the controller
def my_action
  @companies = Company.where(country: 'GB').preload(:ctos)
end

# In the view
- @companies.each do |c|
  = c.ctos.first.last_name
```

The problem with this however is that it would require me to add associations for every single possible type on `Company`.

So the question is, how can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried using a condition on the joined table? `Company.eager_load(:employees).where(employees: { title: 'CTO' })`. It also depends on what set of results you want. Do you want companies with no employee with the title CTO? Then you should use a LEFT OUTER JOIN otherwise it should be an INNER JOIN. http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/

Answer (score 0):

```
companies = Company.where(country: 'GB')  
title = params[:title]
@company_employee = Employee.where(company: companies, title: title).group_by(&:company)
```

@company_employee will be hash with structure { company => [employees] }